# $location.search() used with external function reset whole $scope. How to avoid it?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-routing, angularjs-controller

Example of problem: [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/AvH5up)

Its about controller.js file. I am trying to pass `cleanSearchParameters` output into `$location.search` function and it does work, but after whole `$scope` gets reset.

Check console on example for more details. Try to check some checkboxes.

Comment: I don't know about angular-router, but if you were using angular ui router instead that has a reloadOnSearch option which you can set on a state to prevent it reloading the state when the query parameters change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the `reloadOnSearch` parameter to `false` when you define the route:

```
app.config(['$routeProvider',
    function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
        when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'bug.html',
            controller: 'appController',
            reloadOnSearch: false
        });
    }]);
```

This will allow you to update the search parameters without reloading the controller.

Comment: OMG its works. I was stuck on it from 6 hrs :O thank you so much dude xD